# How should i instruct Appium With Chrome browser to navigate to a given url in PHP? (real device)

Tags: php, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried looking into the php implementation of appium for the get() or navigateTo() methods but I couldn't find it, so I was wondering,  How should I instruct Appium With Chrome browser to navigate to a given url in PHP? (real device)

Answer (score 0):

the answer to this is very simple:

```
$this->url('http://www.google.com');
```

the implementation of the appium client would use this command since it would extend the appium test case library which extends from the fb web driver implementation.